# rails db:migrate errorの意味について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

現在ブログ風アプリ作成のために `rails g model ~~references` を実行して `rails db:migrate` をすると下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `reference' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition:0x00007fca003cbbb8>
Did you mean?  references
```

自分は最初にreferenceと打って実行したためまた再度sをつけて実行しても同じエラーになってしまいました。
app/view/modelの中のファイルを確認してもreferenceの単語が見つからず文字間違いではないのかとも考えているのですが、同じようなエラーにあったことのある方でこのエラーの意味と対処法をご教授して頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `/db` 以下に `ほにゃららReference` が生まれていませんでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。db/migrate/内のcreate.comment.rbを開いたらclass CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.reference :blog

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
endが出ていたのですがmodel g~~referencesをする前に実行してできたファイルなので関係あるのかと思い中を見てもreference自体は含まれていませんでした。もしかしてDB内のどこかのfileに書き足す必要があるのですか？

Comment: うーん、今の質問者さんの `/db` などの状態がどうなっているのか分からないのでなんとも言えません。もしソースコードをバージョン管理なさっていたら動いていた頃のソースコードへ一度戻した後に再度マイグレーションを試されれば良いと思うのですが、如何でしょうか。

Comment: 一度rails reset~DBかmigrateのコマンドを実行して再度rails modelを作りmigrateを実行すればよろしいのでしょうか？

Comment: ソースコード自体をもとに戻せないと意味が無いので、それだと駄目そうです。現状のソースコードがどうなっているかを何らかの方法で質問文に記載いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。また最初からrails newで立ち上げてみます。